# Video view video can't play this video for remote url

Tags: android, xml

I have buttons like this[image]

and i want to compress it from heights just like this[image]

the xml of border is `

```
<solid android:color="@color/orange"/>
<stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="#dddddd"/>

<corners android:radius="10dp"/>

<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="10dp"/>
```

`

what should i do to get desire output?

Comment: just remove padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, But i have cleared this example by putting an another layout and trim it by the button layout. It is not logical but it helps me.

Thanks for support.